# Custom module table not found, the install is not executed

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, sql, install-script

I am learning magento, trying to add a **custom module** where one can upload .xls files and then manage them(basic CRUD operations). Then the .xls files can be executed and inserted into the products db.

This is the error I get in the magento dashboard

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.wine' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wine` AS `main_table
```

As far as I understand, the table wasn't found, which means that my install wasn't ran. This is my **Mymodule/Wine/sql/wine_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('wine'))
    ->addColumn('wine_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, array(
            'auto_increment' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary' => true
        ), 'Wine Id')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255, array(
            'nullable' => false,
        ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 1, array(
            'nullable' => false,
        ), 'Status')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
            'nullable' => false,
        ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('executed_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
            'nullable' => false,
        )
    )
    ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
    ->setOption('charset', 'utf8')
    ->setComment('Wine .xls Files Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The **config.xml** part related to Models/Resources:

```
<models>
    <wine>
        <class>Mymodule_Wine_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>wine_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </wine>
    <wine_mysql4>
        <class>Mymodule_Wine_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <wine>
                <table>wine</table>
            </wine>
        </entities>
    </wine_mysql4>
</models>
<resources>
    <wine_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Mymodule_Wine</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </wine_setup>
    <wine_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_connection</use>
        </connection>
    </wine_write>
    <wine_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </wine_read>
</resources>
```

My model located in **Mymodule/Wine/Model/Wine.php**

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Model_Wine extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('wine/wine');
    }
}
```

**Mymodule/Wine/Model/Resource/Wine.php**

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Model_Resource_Wine extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('wine/wine', 'wine_id');
    }
}
```

**Mymodule/Wine/Model/Resource/Wine/Collection.php**

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Model_Resource_Wine_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        // parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('wine/wine');
    }
}
```

The error only occurs only if this line is present:

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Adminhtml_WineController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
              ->_setActiveMenu('wine/items')
              ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage .xls Files'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage .xls Files'));
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction();
        >> $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('wine/adminhtml_wine')); <<== without this line I can access the backend, but i need the block to be inserted in the dashboard
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the module version in `config.xml` and the check module entry in `core_resource` table if it is there remove it.

```
<modules>
        <Spacename_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Spacename_Modulename>
</modules>
```

Comment: My module is not present in the table.

Comment: @RaduDascălu there will be entry of this `wine_setup` check that

Comment: yes I am sorry, didn't go to the last page :D I've found it. Removed it and everything worked, thank you sir, you are a life saver. Basically couldn't figure it out by myself since all my module files looked fine.